# Use serilog as logging provider in blazor webassembly client app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, serilog

I'd like to use serilog in a blazor webassembly net 6 app, both on client and server sides.
In [this article](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/11/serilog-blazor/) I found out how to relay log entries to server so that they are written in log files.

In this approach however the `Log` static class is used to explicitly add log entries.

I'd like to add serilog as logging provider so that exceptions and automatically generated information are logged, too.

On server side I use

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host
    .UseSerilog((ctx, lc) =>
    {
        lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration);
    });
```

This way everything is passed to serilog.

`UseSerilog` is defined in Serilog.AspNetCore. Unfortunately, if I add Serilog.AspNetCore to my client project, the following error appears:

> NETSDK1082    There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
> available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'

Is there a way to manually add serilog to logging providers, or in alternative, is there a way to add Serilog.AspNetCore package to client project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been able to add Serilog to my client application logging providers by adding the **Serilog.Extensions.Logging** NuGet package.

Then I used the following code:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Extensions.Logging;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

/* ... */

/* Serilog configuration
 * here I use BrowserHttp sink to send log entries to my Server app
 */
var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"))
    .WriteTo.BrowserHttp(endpointUrl: $"{builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress}ingest", controlLevelSwitch: levelSwitch)
    .CreateLogger();

/* this is used instead of .UseSerilog to add Serilog to providers */
builder.services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip, but as of Net7 Blazor WASM the following is needed instead of the last line. (from the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` readme):

```builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));```

Comment: It actually works both ways, however since your code is the official one, I'll update my answer. Thank you JasonS!

Comment: Why can't it be configured via appSettings.json?

Comment: It can be configured from appSettings.json:
 `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).CreateLogger();`
 where `builder` is `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)`