# How to use Serilog in Blazor Web Assembly Project

Tags: blazor-webassembly, serilog

Good day to every one.
I will be thankful, if someone can suggest how to implement **Serilog** in **Blazor Web Assembly Project**. I have found different solutions on different platform to implement Serilog for logging purposes in Blazor server project, but unfortunately not in Blazor Web Assembly project.

Comment: check this ans. it is for adding serilog into blazor webassembly client app https://stackoverflow.com/a/71299669/9247039